# XML::Simple End tag mismatch

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8

I have a valid XML file here 
http://pastebin.com/EQw8rZDS

But when I use XML::Simple on some of my servers this is giving an error 
"End tag mismatch"
(perl 5.8.8 and XML::Simple 2.20 )

I am not sure what package needs to be upgraded

This is the code here

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $xs = XML::Simple->new();
my $xml1 =  $xs->XMLin($ARGV[0]) ;

print Dumper($xml1);
```

Comment: I would suggest not using `XML::Simple` in the first place. It isn't, it's _for_ simple XML. Even the docs  suggest it's use in new code is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I added a line

`$XML::Simple::PREFERRED_PARSER = 'XML::Parser';`

Now this is working fine

Comment: That might imply that the XML::SAX::PurePerl parser was being used.  If you can provide an XML document that triggers the problem then it might be worth filing a bug.